# Corrupted SDcard?

Tags: corrupt

Is this a sign of a corrupted SD card? It happens just after boot up finishes the code. If so, I might know the reason why. When I tried rebooting my Raspberry Pi twice today, it wouldn't shutdown fully. It would go to the last line of the shutdown stage but never turn off. [image]

Comment: That's certainly looking a bit funky. Backup the important stuff and try a clean install.

Comment: Will do later to late today. Also tried this on both of my raspberry pis and got the same result.

Comment: Ok when i place my sd card into my mac it shows boot, how do i restore files such as python scripts?